# Find MongoDB array that has two equal elements

Tags: mongodb

I can use the [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) and `$eq` query operators to find MongoDB documents that have two equal fields:

```js
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $eq: [ '$name', '$moniker' ] } })
```

But that doesn't seem to work when the two fields are array elements:

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: ["$arr.0.foo", "$arr.1.foo"]
  }
})
```

Let alone that it doesn't work on arrays of objects:

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: ["$arrO.0.foo", "$arrO.1.foo"]
  }
})
```

That query outputs both documents ([MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/J9UTWkc6Yzt)). What am I doing wrong?

Here's the collection:

```
[
  {
    name: "doc1",
    moniker: "doc1",
    arr: [1, 2],
    arrO: [ {foo: 1}, {foo: 2} ]
  },
  {
    name: "doc2",
    arr: [3, 3],
    arrO: [ {foo: 3}, {foo: 3} ]  // this should be found
  }
]
```

I've looked at [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) but that doesn't (easily) allow accessing fields in arrays of objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$arrayElemAt` instead of `.dot` notation

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      { "$arrayElemAt": ["$arr", 0] },
      { "$arrayElemAt": ["$arr", 1] }
    ]
  }
})
```

[**MongoPlayground**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x4b8JfBM4pP)

Comment: Looks like we were typing the same answer at the same time :) I've updated my question to explain when $arrayElemAt doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! Also, `'arrO.1': { $exists: true },` is necessary, otherwise arrays with 0 elements will match too.

Answer (score -1):

I've found a poor workaround using [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/), but I don't understand why the `"$arr.0"` syntax didn't work.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      { $arrayElemAt: ["$arr", 0] },
      { $arrayElemAt: ["$arr", 1] },

    ]
  }
})
```

The workaround is poor because it doesn't work on arrays of objects: how do you get only field `foo` from array `arr` at index `i`? The array syntax `$arr.i.foo` makes that as easy as it can be.

Comment: It is not poor workout around. The thing is "You cannot use field names inside the `expr`".

Comment: @Ashh: is that a quote from the MongoDB docs? I can't find it. And [you can definitely use field paths](https://mongoplayground.net/p/7hKaei_XlNW).

Comment: Field names in the sense without the `$` mark, just as we do for query operators. `db.collection.find({ "field.0": 1 })`

Comment: @Ashh: not sure I understand. Did you find that quote somewhere on the MongoDB site? Or did you come up with it? [This section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/#use-the-array-index-to-query-for-a-field-in-the-embedded-document) shows how to use "dot notation" to "query conditions for field in a document at a particular index or position of the array": `db.collection('inventory').find({
  'instock.0.qty': { $lte: 20 }
});`. Where did you find that `$expr` doesn't support that same dot notation?

Comment: Ok see what is `field.0`? Here you want to compare with the 0th element but after using `$expr` now it consideres it as field name. Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8s9J1pHhuu0). Whereas if you don't use `$expr` it will consider it as the index. Something like `db.collection.find({
  "arrO.0": 1
})`

Comment: Hey wow! I have just seen... You have a great wikipedia blog... If you need more help regarding the mongo database then It will be great pleasure, I am always here. Thank you!!!

Comment: @Ashh In case you mean the Wikipedia page about me, thanks :) And thanks for the offer! Can you [apply this change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822469/find-mongodb-array-that-has-two-equal-elements/56822493?noredirect=1#comment100197849_56822495) so I can accept your answer? I've also reported [the issue we've been talking about](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-12838), let's see what the MongoDB team says about it.

Comment: ***you mean the Wikipedia page about me*** Yesss. And I have updated my answer. And also Your profile is marvellous, attractive. Glad to meet and answer you. **Anytime Available**